# Does WebKit require full class selectors?

Tags: javascript, swift, ios8, webkit, wkwebview

It seems there's an issue with selecting by class name when using WebKit JavaScript execution within a WKWebView and WKUserScript.

Consider the following HTML element:

```
<div class="small product highlighted">Text to match</div>
```

From Safari, Chrome, et al., I can match by just one of the clases. E.g., the following JavaScript matching techniques works just fine:

```
document.querySelector(".product").innerText
```

But if the same JavaScript snippet is called as part of a WKUserScript, it fails to find the element.

Instead, it seems I need to provide the full CSS class declaration. When I do, things work fine within the WKUserScript:

```
document.querySelector(".small.product.highlighted").innerText
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue? This seems like a bug, or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `.product` should work. What happens if you use `[class~=product]`?

Comment: I agree. .product should work. But it doesn't. That's why I think this may be an Apple bug. I get the same result matching via the attribute matcher [class~=product]. As before it works in the full Safari browser but not within a WKUserScript. The only matcher I've been able to get to work in the WKUserScript has been the full class declaration with all three classes.